# How to remove FOUC in wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fouc

I have a development site I'm building on wordpress (a href="http://scottmcrae.thecrossagency.net/">dev site here, using DRY theme ([original theme here](http://themeforest.net/item/dry-one-page-responsive-wordpress-theme/4232933)). The original theme had a preloader - I disabled it because the site took longer to load with it on than off, and it also would refresh/preload the page again when user submits the contact form on the bottom. When I load the page, the nav bar area first loads with either more height or more padding/margin (can't tell) and then snaps into the proper size after a brief moment. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: it depends on what's causing it to snap. you haven't provided anything in your question that would help us figure that out for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 6 stylesheet links at the end of the document. Move them inside `<head>`.

PageSpeed can help find these problems.

- formreset.css
- datepicker.css
- formsmain.css
- readyclass.css
- browsers.css
- style.css